# How do I make myself an anonymous reviewer in Mac Word 2011?

Tags: macos, mac, microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2011

I'm an editor and I'm trying to change my reviewer information in Mac Word 2011. Right now, my only option seems to be Word > Preferences > Remove personal information from this file on save. However, this removes the time stamp, as well. 
Is there any way to change my name to "Editor" on the tracked changes and comments?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You may change the user name by going to `File -> Options`, and change your user name in the `General` tab to `Editor`. After that, any changes you committed will show as "Editor".

You may also want to go to the file properties in the OS to verify/make sure that the word file saved has "Editor" as the author